# Contar y obtener información de los marcadores en Google maps

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps

Tengo un mapa de Google, agrego y elimino los marcadores al hacer clic. Al final necesito poder obtener todos los marcadores que el usuario coloco en el mapa.

Lo agrego de la siguiente forma:

```
marcadores: any[] = []

placeMarker(position, map) {
  ....
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
  });

  marker.addListener("dblclick", function (e) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  });

  this.marcadores.push(marker)
}
```

¿Alguna orientación?

Comment: Guardalos en un array

Comment: Al inicio pon `let marcadores = [];` y al final pon `marcadores.push(marker);`

Comment: si, eso hago, pero al momento de que el usuario elimine el marcador como hago para que se elimine del array marcadores??

Comment: Donde almacenas ese array? En el localStorage?

Comment: Lo eliminas con botones? Haciendo doble click sobre el elemento? Está en una tabla? Agrega un poco más de código para poder responder mejor

Comment: Agregue el codigo mas completo, los marcadores estan en un array y los elimino haciendo doble click

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta para que sea en Angular, asegúrate de agregar las etiquetas correspondientes para facilitar las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
function removeMarker(marker) {
  marker.setMap(null); // Eliminar el marcador del mapa
  var index = marcadores.indexOf(marker);
  if (index !== -1) {
    marcadores.splice(index, 1); // Eliminar el marcador del array
  }
}
```

La función removeMarker busca el índice del marcador en el array marcadores y lo elimina usando el método `splice()`. Luego, se llama al método `setMap(null)` para eliminar el marcador del mapa.

```
//En el método addListener le asocias la función
marker.addListener('dblclick', function() {
  removeMarker(marker);
});
```

Comment: marker.addListener('dblclick', function() {
  this.removeMarker(marker);
});

me da el siguiente error (estoy usando angular)
 
Property 'removeMarker' does not exist on type 'Marker'.ts(2339)
any

removeMarker(marker) {
    marker.setMap(null); // Eliminar el marcador del mapa
    var index = marcadores.indexOf(marker);
    if (index !== -1) {
      marcadores.splice(index, 1); // Eliminar el marcador del array
    }
  }

Comment: Si estas usando Angular hubieras agregado la etiqueta.

Answer (score 1):

En Angular:

Suponiendo que lo tienes en una lista (aunque no importa mucho) el código sería el siguiente:

**HTML**

```
<li (dblclick)="borrarMarcador(i)" *ngFor="let marcador of marcadores; let i = index">
```

**Component**

Acá te sugiero que no uses del tipo any para tu array, dale un tipo. Create tu propia interfaz o utiliza la de Google Maps.

```
  borrarMarcador(i: number) {
    this.marcadores[i].setMap(null);
    this.marcadores.splice(i, 1);
    this.guardarMarcadores();
  }
}
```

Vuelves a llamar la función de guardar marcadores para que se actualice la fuente de tus datos (si es que los recibes de alguna parte)